# Get specific column after iterating over each row of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

As a first step, I want to plot the regression on time for each gene taking all the variables present in the model, hence using all the genes, was performed. In `df5`, the columns represent time and rows represent gene expression.

```
fig = px.scatter(df5, x='0', y='prediction',marginal_x='histogram', marginal_y='histogram',color='split', trendline='ols')
```

However, now I want to get the first column of each row after iterating over the rows of a pandas dataframe. My code raised `IndexingError: Too many indexers` error.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score, mean_absolute_error
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFdr, chi2
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, MinMaxScaler

# Split data into training and test splits
train_idx, test_idx = train_test_split(df5.index, test_size=.25, random_state=0)
df5["split"] = "train"
df5.loc[test_idx, "split"] = "test"

# Inputs and targets
X = df5.iloc[:, 1:-1]
y = df5.iloc[:, 0]

X_train = df5.loc[train_idx, ["4", "8", "12", "24", "48"]]
y_train = df5.loc[train_idx, "0"]

# Linear regression prediction
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
df5['prediction'] = model.predict(X)
```

Now, I want to plot the regression on time for each gene.

```
# Scatter plot 
for i, j in df5.iterrows():
  fig = px.scatter(j, x=j.iloc[:,0], y=j['prediction'],marginal_x='histogram', marginal_y='histogram',color='split', trendline='ols')
  fig.update_traces(histnorm='probability', selector={'type':'histogram'})
  fig.add_shape(type="line", line=dict(dash='dash'),x0=y.min(), y0=y.min(),x1=y.max(), y1=y.max())
  fig.show()
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-342-7353b9534134> in <module>()
      1 # Scatter plot
      2 for i, j in df5.iterrows():
----> 3   fig = px.scatter(j, x=j.iloc[:,0], y=j['prediction'],marginal_x='histogram', marginal_y='histogram',color='split', trendline='ols')
      4   fig.update_traces(histnorm='probability', selector={'type':'histogram'})
      5   fig.add_shape(type="line", line=dict(dash='dash'),x0=y.min(), y0=y.min(),x1=y.max(), y1=y.max())

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    923                 with suppress(KeyError, IndexError):
    924                     return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
--> 925             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
    926         else:
    927             # we by definition only have the 0th axis

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
   1504     def _getitem_tuple(self, tup: tuple):
   1505 
-> 1506         self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
   1507         with suppress(IndexingError):
   1508             return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _has_valid_tuple(self, key)
    749         Check the key for valid keys across my indexer.
    750         """
--> 751         self._validate_key_length(key)
    752         for i, k in enumerate(key):
    753             try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _validate_key_length(self, key)
    790     def _validate_key_length(self, key: Sequence[Any]) -> None:
    791         if len(key) > self.ndim:
--> 792             raise IndexingError("Too many indexers")
    793 
    794     def _getitem_tuple_same_dim(self, tup: tuple):

IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

Data:

`df5.head().to_dict()`

```
{'0': {'DNAJB6 /// TMEM135': 0.30131649339447103,
  'DNAJC14': 0.2255444383216058,
  'DNAJC15': 0.25789169794229455,
  'DNAJC30': 0.11388797858763917,
  'DNAJC9': 0.11205541676885071},
 '12': {'DNAJB6 /// TMEM135': 0.28354614480145346,
  'DNAJC14': 0.2343653660720247,
  'DNAJC15': 0.2406210529534205,
  'DNAJC30': 0.11229754447748205,
  'DNAJC9': 0.12045170255898871},
 '24': {'DNAJB6 /// TMEM135': 0.27395808285292367,
  'DNAJC14': 0.2246018336027369,
  'DNAJC15': 0.22347959865906092,
  'DNAJC30': 0.11379897713291527,
  'DNAJC9': 0.10622530623273815},
 '4': {'DNAJB6 /// TMEM135': 0.2949284643966144,
  'DNAJC14': 0.22905481299223704,
  'DNAJC15': 0.22312009403152122,
  'DNAJC30': 0.13114878202076288,
  'DNAJC9': 0.12991396178392187},
 '48': {'DNAJB6 /// TMEM135': 0.289873135093664,
  'DNAJC14': 0.2349502215468218,
  'DNAJC15': 0.17706771640592167,
  'DNAJC30': 0.10857074282633467,
  'DNAJC9': 0.13001391250069522},
 '8': {'DNAJB6 /// TMEM135': 0.2794865791356734,
  'DNAJC14': 0.22228815371920396,
  'DNAJC15': 0.22912018863353348,
  'DNAJC30': 0.11799998627920205,
  'DNAJC9': 0.10520854728987451},
 'prediction': {'DNAJB6 /// TMEM135': 0.2855688204171829,
  'DNAJC14': 0.22191146957280725,
  'DNAJC15': 0.24908287098429563,
  'DNAJC30': 0.12514969134896878,
  'DNAJC9': 0.11705504942609991},
 'split': {'DNAJB6 /// TMEM135': 'test',
  'DNAJC14': 'test',
  'DNAJC15': 'train',
  'DNAJC30': 'train',
  'DNAJC9': 'train'}}
```

Comment: I'm trying to set `x` as the first column using `x=j.iloc[:,0]`

Comment: The question here isn't really about plotly, but rather how to get the structure of your data that you'd like to plot. Please explain a bit further what exactly it is you're looking to accomplish here. I'm not sure what you mean by `first column of each row`.  What does an example of that look like?

Comment: The return value of iterrows() is a series, so .loc cannot be used. So we should convert it to a data frame. `df = j.to_frame()`

Comment: @r-beginners If you're already on this I'm just going to lean back and enjoy the show =)

Comment: I've edited the question to add more information.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate solution to your problem of getting the first column is because you are giving iloc a row and a column location, when referring to a row (`too many indexers`). You can fix this and get just the (scalar) value for column `0` with `x=j.iloc[0]`.

However, your code has other problems. I think you're trying to do something like this?

```
fig = px.scatter(df5, x='0', y='prediction', marginal_x='histogram', marginal_y='histogram',color='split', 
           trendline='ols', hover_name=df5.index)
fig.update_traces(histnorm='probability', selector={'type':'histogram'})
fig.add_shape(type="line", line=dict(dash='dash'),x0=y.min(), y0=y.min(),x1=y.max(), y1=y.max())
fig.show()
```

[image]